# How to create user tables in Acumatica

Tags: sql, acumatica

I need to create some user defined tables for an Acumatica customization.  I am a SQL developer, so I am accustomed to creating tables using Management Studio.  But when I try that in an Acumatica database, I get this error:

```
This backend version is not supported to design diagrams or tables.
```

I'm assuming the creation of tables is something that takes place using Visual Studio, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: You can probably find the answer to your question in our database guideline : https://help.acumatica.com/(W(2))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=5659adfe-3e4a-45a6-a94a-a33c2f955194

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and do not use the Express edition:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Comment: The developer version of SQL works well. I no longer use express for development environments. Just an alternative.

Comment: I believe the product branded "SQL Server Management Studio Express" is deprecated by Microsoft and should be avoided because it can lead to errors like the one in this question. I think the product named "SQL Server Express" doesn't have those limitation as it ships with a non Express version of Management Studio but I haven't tried it.